# parsing arguments with Codeigniter form_validation callback for file input

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, validation

I have a upload input and am trying to parse an argument to callback function via the CI form_validation library.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('orderfile', 'Order Form'," trim|callback_upload_check[$account_id]");
```

This calls:

```
public function upload_check($str, $id)
{
    $errors = $this->do_upload($id);

    if(isset($errors['error']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('upload_check', $errors['error']);

        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The [Codeigniter Userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) states that when calling the function, the first argument is parsed as the second argument inside the function.

Neither arguments are parsed through. I found this post on the [Codeigniter Forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/100710/#531862)
This seems to explain what is happening (variables are stripped). If i change the to `<input type="text" />` the params work...
Is there anyway of getting around this problem?

Comment: I had it required but it works a bit weird on upload inputs, it thinks it hasn't been filled even when it has. Seems like there are conflicts between $_POST and $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit your code like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('orderfile', 'Order Form'," trim|callback_upload_check[".$account_id."]");
```

i also noticed that in your form_validation->set_rules you are not passing any value for id so in your function you should do :

```
public function upload_check($str, $id=0){..}
```

Comment: in your callback_upload_check shouldnt you pass $id also ?

Comment: it says that if you pass one argument when calling the function it appears as the second in the function

Comment: These suggestions do not make any difference, its not that the function is failing/erroring due to syntax, its that the parameters are possibly being stripped or for some reason not being parsed through to the callback function (upload_check)

Comment: no , there is no such thing , as "you pass one argument when calling the function it appears as the second in the function" , just remove the $str and try with only $id

Comment: from codeigniter userguide `To invoke a callback just put the function name in a rule, with "callback_" as the rule prefix. If you need to receive an extra parameter in your callback function, just add it normally after the function name between square brackets, as in: "callback_foo[bar]", then it will be passed as the second argument of your callback function`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function to:

```
public function upload_check($orderfile)
{
    $errors = $this->do_upload($orderfile);

    if(isset($errors['error']))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('upload_check', $errors['error']);

        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same problem, I finally realized the second parameter comes back in quotes, so if you pass an `$id` with the value `1`, it actually comes back as `"1"`.

So, to the original question, you need to callback the function like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('orderfile', 'Order Form'," trim|callback_upload_check[".$account_id."]");
```

And in your call back function:

```
public function upload_check($str, $id){
  $actual_id=str_replace('"', "", $id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config =array(
       
        array(
            "field" => "userEmail",
            "label" => ":userEmail:",
            "rules" => "required|valid_email",
        ),
        array(
            "field" => "userPassword",
            "label" => ":userPassword:",
            "rules" => "required|min_length[8]",
        ),
        
    );

    $error_messages = array(
        "required" => "{field} the field is required.",
        "min_length" => "{field} the field value is so short",
        "valid_email" => "{field} please valid email",
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_message($error_messages);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $alert =preg_replace("/(\n)+/m", ' ', strip_tags(validation_errors()));
        $explode =explode(':', $alert);
        
        $arr =array();
        for($i=1; $i < count($explode); $i+=2){
            $y=$i;
            $j =++$y;
            $arr[$explode[$i]] = $explode[$j];
        }
        print json_encode($arr);
        
    } else { 
            //process
    
    }
```

Comment: firstly, create config and error_messages for validation. And if inside in validation scope , validation's error message have a some html element. Clean this elements. 

And split with ":" . Generate new array label name = key and message=value.

finally return json_encode data. Because i m recieve with javascript. You can return only array data.

Comment: People does not read comments, sorry I ment commetns in the answer  (inside the code)